# Mule Esb CE sftp outbound endpoint invoke form code (custom java transformer)

Tags: sftp, esb, mule

Is it possible to invoke sftp  outbound endpoint, and send a file, through the code? 
I have a reference to a File object in java code (in a custom transformer), and I want to invoke sftp outbound endpoint and pass that File reference. Is this doable?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it a `FileInputStream`, that should work.

```
muleContext.getClient().dispatch("sftp://...", new FileInputStream(file), null);
```

If not, you'll have to pass it a `byte[]`.

Note that `dispatch` is asynchronous: the call will return immediately while the SFTP communication occurs. if you want to wait until it's done, use `send` with a time-out as last parameter.

Since you have several SFTP connectors configured, you'll have to specify the connector name in the URL. Supposing you want to dispatch using `SFTP_Upload_Connector`, you'll have to use:

```
muleContext.getClient().dispatch("sftp://...?connector=SFTP_Upload_Connector", new FileInputStream(file), null);
```

If you want to set a particular destination file name, pass it as a property named `filename` in the properties map, for example using:

```
muleContext.getClient().dispatch("sftp://...?connector=SFTP_Upload_Connector", new FileInputStream(file), Collections.singletonMap("filename", "somen_ame"));
```

Comment: Now I'm getting error message:  Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are at least 2 connectors matching protocol "sftp", 
so the connector to use must be specified on the endpoint using the 'connector' property/attribute. 
Connectors in your configuration that support "sftp" are: SFTP_connector, SFTP_Upload_Connector,

Comment: Ah, you didn't say you had configured several SFTP connectors :) No problem, you just have to designate the connector you want to use in the URL, I've amended my response accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, works good. One more question, how to set destination file name?

Comment: Added a note in my answer about the usage of the `filename` property.